# Running Craft with Docker (or something similar)

Tags: environments

Has anyone had success with setting up Craft using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)?

I've stumbled across some [Dockerfiles for WordPress](https://github.com/eugeneware/docker-wordpress-nginx) and other CMS's but couldn't find much in the way of Craft. I'll be exploring this a bit myself over the next week, but was hoping some people in the community may have a few good pointers or tips or even cautions.

To elaborate, I'm looking for alternatives to MAMP as well, or other development environment tools for working with Craft.

Comment: I've been looking at Docker too, I'll be watching for your findings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today the [Craft docs](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/migrating-from-craft-nitro-to-ddev) note deprecating [Nitro](https://github.com/craftcms/nitro) in favor of [DDEV](https://ddev.com/) or similar projects.

There is also some good content on [Craft Quest about using DDEV](https://craftquest.io/courses/ddev-and-craft-cms-quick-start-guide/43386).

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Laravel Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead) for local dev (and [Forge](https://forge.laravel.com) controlled VPS' for staging). Both have been hugely successful for me – I've not touched MAMP for months.

Craft works off-the-shelf with both.

Comment: Niceeeeeee. Thanks for this. Giving it a shot now!

Comment: I notice Homestead 2 was just announced today, I've not had a chance to try this version yet but I'd guess it should all be fine.

Comment: I'm giving it a shot now. Will let you know my success as well.

Comment: This may (or may not) be helpful: https://laracasts.com/lessons/say-hello-to-laravel-homestead-two

Comment: So it definitely works. However, I noticed that once I run `homestead destroy`, my database is purged. Do you connect to a remote database or one locally? If locally, how do you keep it from being destroyed when you restart your machine or homestead?

I did notice the suspend command, but wonder what happens if I forget :x

Comment: I always use local DB. You shouldn't really have any need to destroy the environment (I never do). You're maybe looking for `vagrant suspend`? Personally I leave it as-is and just issue a `vagrant up` if I ever have to reboot the host machine.

Comment: Interesting. Looks like it wasn't an issue when I just restarted. I guess I assumed you would need to destroy and restart it each time. This is pretty rad.

Comment: Indeed! I never touch it apart from a `vagrant provision` if I add any new vhosts.

Answer (score 2):

I am creating an image to help me test Craft.

https://github.com/gabrielmoreira/docker-craft

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is interested - I did a quick mashup of the Craft and Laravel Homestead documentation to outline the process I went through for setting up my first Craft site locally on a Vagrant/Homestead box.

Thanks to the guys over at Straight Up Craft for the video about Vagrant and Craft which introduced me to Homestead﻿

https://medium.com/@mattcollins_6/setting-up-a-local-dev-environment-for-craft-cms-using-laravel-homestead-2724be3954a5

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this tutorial on using vagrant with craft. You could use this as an alternative to MAMP. 
http://straightupcraft.com/articles/setting-up-craft-with-vagrant

Comment: Awesome thank you.

Comment: Cool this actually touches on more options other than homestead as well. I got homestead working, and will be giving Forge a go again in light of all this, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have. I even wrote an article that describes the application I created to automate the install process less than two minutes.

[CraftCMS + Docker Dev Environment in seconds](https://medium.com/@bshelling/craft-mac-n-cheez-creates-a-craftcms-docker-dev-environment-in-seconds-33731a1aa685)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Docker setup for Craft CMS as a Composer project:

https://github.com/nystudio107/craft

Here is a full Craft website in Docker that you can spin up locally:

https://github.com/nystudio107/devmode

...and here is a comprehensive article on the Docker setup:

https://nystudio107.com/blog/an-annotated-docker-config-for-frontend-web-development

related:

https://nystudio107.com/blog/dock-life-using-docker-for-all-the-things

Comment: That docker article is super in depth. Probably a really good option for those who want to roll their own setup and are afraid to get their hands dirty!